# Existence and uniqueness of the solution for the Cauchy problem for ODE system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Please help me to solve the following problem:

I got the system of differential equation $$\dot x_1=2t \sqrt{|x_1|}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_2-1}}, \dot x_2=x_1x_2.$$
I also got initial conditions:

1. $(t_0,x_1^0,x_2^0)=(0, 1,2),$
2. $(t_0,x_1^0,x_2^0)=(0, 0,1),$
3. $(t_0,x_1^0,x_2^0)=(0, 0,2).$

For every case I must determine if Cauchy problem for the system has the solution.

In second part of the problem I have to determine for the following points

4. $(t_0,x_1^0,x_2^0)=(0, 2,3),$
5. $(t_0,x_1^0,x_2^0)=(0, 0,1),$
6. $(t_0,x_1^0,x_2^0)=(1, 0,4).$

if the solution for the Cauchy problem is unique.

Unfortunately I have no idea where to start and I was not able to find relevant section in my textbook. Can you please guide me what should I know to solve this problem, so I will attempt to post my solution for your review.

Thanks a lot for your hints and solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial conditions 2 and 5 are not allowed since the r.h.s. is not defined on that points.

Indeed, the r.h.s. of the system $f = (f_1, f_2)$ is defined and continuous in $\Omega :=\{(x_1, x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\ x_2 > 1\}$.
By Peano's existence theorem, every Cauchy problem with initial data in $\Omega$ has a solution, hence in the cases 1, 3, 4, 6 there exists at least one solution.

For the uniqueness part, the only problem is for $x_1 = 0$, where $f_1$ is not locally Lipschitz continuous, while $f_1$ is of class $C^1$ in $\{x_1>0\}$ and $\{x_1 < 0\}$ (where it is defined).

Hence, for the condition 4 one has local uniqueness.

Uniqueness holds also for condition 6, because one has $\dot{x}_1 (0) > 0$, so that the solution cannot stay on the discontinuity $\{x_1=0\}$.

Comment: So the answers are: 1 - has solution 2 - no solution 3 - has solution, 4 has uniqueness 5 can not talk about it since there is no solution 6 - has uniqueness, right?

Comment: Yes, these should be the correct answers.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your enormous help, detailed answers and patience. Please come back tomorrow!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answers. I recently had ODE test and there the problem extremely close to this one (another constants, you can think the same). First part of the question was accepted, but in second was the mistake. Initially I thought it was my lecturer mistake, but all mistakes I made in that test were perfectly valid and I got several explanations about them today here. Can you please analyse more carefully second part (4,5,6) of this problem - there should be a mistake. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd say that 4 and 5 are correct. In my opinion also 6 is correct, but one can discuss if uniqueness is only for local solutions or for maximal ones. Perhaps you can tell me what's the point.